# Why does variable combined with group by and aggregate functions only keep the last value

Tags: mysql, variables, aggregate-functions

I use Mysql, the query statement is:

```
SELECT is_superuser, @superuser := is_superuser, @superuser
FROM use GROUP BY is_superuser;
```

The result is:

```
is_superuser  @superuser := is_superuser  @superuser
    0                0                       0
    1                1                       1
```

But when I execute the following statement:

```
SELECT is_superuser, @superuser := count(*), @superuser
FROM use GROUP BY is_superuser;
```

The result is:

```
is_superuser  @superuser := count(*)  @superuser
    0                11                      1
    1                1                       1
```

"@superuse" only have the last value.
My expectations are:

```
is_superuser  @superuser := count(*)  @superuser
    0                11                      11
    1                1                       1
```

How to understand the above situation, if I want to use the variable for secondary aggregation can be achieved?

Comment: You cannot use UDV by this way. `COUNT(*)` is really calculated before output expressions evaluation.

Comment: @Akina I don't understand, is there a document about that?

Comment: No, the order of steps during the query execution is not documented. Server is free in selection, and the performance is its preferred criteria. AFAIR the output list expression evaluation order is documented as "according to the order in output expressions list" but I cannot find this place in RM now...

Comment: @Akina In "https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html", I found "function_call" is also a expression.